# Fail on running Android Studio emulator with React Native on Windows

Tags: windows, react-native, android-studio, ubuntu

instagramClone[instagram-clone]$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
/bin/sh: 1: /home/leyla/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: not found
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > The SDK directory '/mnt/c/Users/leylali/CodeFellows/401/react-native-learning/instagramClone/android/C:\Users\leylali\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > The SDK directory '/mnt/c/Users/leylali/CodeFellows/401/react-native-learning/instagramClone/android/C:\Users\leylali\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
at runOnAllDevices (/mnt/c/Users/leylali/CodeFellows/401/react-native-learning/instagramClone/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow!
It looks like you have just pasted your log output. This is going to make is super hard for anyone to understand what you are trying to do. 

How about posting some of your code snippets to show what you have tried and what you are trying to do. 

Also, if you have the time, give this a read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Make sure the given SDK path is correct. /mnt/c/Users/leylali/CodeFellows/401/react-native-learning/instagramClone/android/C:\Users\leylali\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk